# Date format problem in view

Tags: 7, views

hello I encounter difficulties to display a date in the correct format in a view.

I souhaire display my dates like this 2009-07-19T03:00:00+01:00

I created a new format here / admin / config / regional / date-time / formats
here that `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`

Then I created a new type of date and selected my new format.
When I go to my view, I select my new date format but the field shows a different format 2016-03-17+01:00 +01:00

So I have a time zone more and I miss the hour, minutes and seconds.
Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: is this Drupal 7

Comment: In views, for date formatter select **custom** and put `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP` and see what happens.

Comment: hello, yes I have set the parameter fields on my custom date

Comment: like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsd8S.jpg)?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2689945

Comment: I do not put my screenshot on this site so I opened a post on drupal. Look in the message I have attached pictures

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this, which works fine for me:

For date format select `Custom` and then enter `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no personalized format in my view.
Watching capture date1.jpg

Comment: Use "custom" instead of "google shopping"

Comment: I have only the short format, medium, long, google shopping and weather.

Comment: that's very weird, custom should show up under short format as seen [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195105/date-format-problem-in-view/195191?noredirect=1#answer-195191)

Comment: yes it is weird, but I want to display the discount date. Maybe is there a problem with the discount Module